# Awk command inside a for loop

Tags: shell-script, awk, for

I try, with no success, to use an `awk` command inside a `for` loop.

I've got a variable which contains a series of strings that I want to cut with `awk` to get the data.

I know how to do that but what I really want is to cut the data successively.

So I've got this variable:

```
var="data1,data2,data3"
```

And here where I am right now:

```
for ((i=1; i<=3; i++))
do
    echo $(awk -F, '{print $1}' <<< $var)
done
```

I try to replace the `$1` by the loop `$i` but without success.

Comment: Every character in between a pair of single quotes is treated as a literal character.

Comment: What is your real use-case? looping over awk seems unnecessary here (for exaple in bash you could use a parameter substitution `echo "${var//,/$'\n'}"`)

Comment: Actually the variable will contains urls from a zenity form. I want to use these urls separately so I have to get each one of them independently.

Comment: Relevant, but not a good solution in this case: [How to assign value at run time in AWK command](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/496869)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do by using double quotes in the awk script to inject the shell variable into it. You still want to keep one literal `$` in it, which you can do by escaping it with backslash:

```
echo $(awk -F, "{print \$$i}" <<<$var)
```

This will expand the `$i` to `1`, `2` and `3` in each of the iterations, therefore awk will see `$1`, `$2` and `$3` which will make it expand each of the fields.

Another possibility is to inject the shell variable as an awk variable using the `-v` flag:

```
echo $(awk -F, -v i="$i" '{print $i}' <<<$var)
```

That assigns the awk variable *i* to the contents of the shell variable with the same name. Variables in awk don't use a `$`, which is used for fields, so `$i` is enough to refer to the *i*-th field if *i* is a variable in awk.

Assigning an awk variable with `-v` is generally a safer approach, particularly when it can contain arbitrary sequences of characters, in that case there's less risk that the contents will be executed as awk code against your intentions. But since in your case the variable holds a single integer, that's less of a concern.

Yet another option is to use a `for` loop in awk itself. See awk documentation (or search this site) for more details on how to do that.

Comment: ... or set the input record separator appropriately `awk -v RS='[,\n]' 1 <<< "$var"` (or maybe more portably `printf "$var" | awk -v RS=, 1` )

Comment: @steeldriver That awk script will print all three fields at once. Which is ok given the OP is doing _just that_... I ended up focusing the answer on extracting a single field on the assumption they were interested in executing other commands in the shell loop (which might have been the motivation for using one in the first place...)

Comment: Understood - that's why I commented on the OP to clarify what they *really* want to do ;)

Comment: The _first_ is an injection (and a security concern), the _second_ one (using `-v`) is not an injection.

Comment: @Kusalananda Good point! Rephrased to use "Assign" which is what the awk man page uses for `-v`, hopefully that's clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, your answer solved my problem!
First time I post a question here after years of reading posts. Not disappointed. Such a great community!

Answer (score 1):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) can accept both `j` (as variable) and `$j` (as field index):

```sh
for i in 1 2 3; do echo "$var" | awk -v j=$i -F , '{print $j}'; done
```

`$i` in the example "confused" `awk` which one to use (shell or its own variable - taking precedence) as both are referred to with `$` prefix.

#### note

[sh](/questions/tagged/sh) shell which is standard for "portable" scripting do not support:

`(( i=1; i<=3; i++; ))` and `<<< $var` constructs

Also you might consider using `seq` command in `for` loop for finer control in number sequence generation, if available.

Comment: Your loop would only work if you happened to have three files called `1`, `2` and `3` in the current directory.  Also, you use variable expansion unquoted in the shell which may have unwanted consequences if the data contains filename patterns (like `*`). The `echo` may furthermore modify the data if it contains backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` seems excessive in this circumstance, how about a `tr` and a while-loop:

```
tr , '\n' <<<"$var" | while read; do
  echo $REPLY
done
```

Output:

```
data1
data2
data3
```

Comment: Great. `REPLY` being the default `name` argument for `read` built-in shell command.

Comment: Note that this requires that the shell uses a default variable to put the data in from `read`, which `bash` happens to do, but this is not standard. Also, your `read` command may modify the data if it contains backslashes, and may strip flanking whitespace from the values.  It would also read values with embedded newlines as multiple values.  You additionally need `"$REPLY"` to stop the shell from splitting the value and from performing filename expansion on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

var='data1,data2,data3'

unset data
while [ "$var" != "$data" ]; do
    data=${var%%,*}    # delete first comma and the bit after it
    var=${var#*,}      # delete bit up to first comma (and the comma)

    printf 'data = "%s"\n' "$data"
done
```

Here, we use variable substitutions to get each successive comma-delimited data field from the value of the `var` variable.  The first assignment to `data` in the loop will remove everything from `$var` after the first comma.  The `var` variable is then modified so that the first bit up to the first comma is deleted.

This continues until `"$var" = "$data"` which means that nothing more can be done to the string.

This way of doing it would allow us to handle comma-separated data strings that contain embedded newlines:

```
var='line1
line2,data2,last bit
goes here'
```

With the above values in `var`, the above script would output

```
data = "line1
line2"
data = "data2"
data = "last bit
goes here"
```

---

Not caring about embedded newlines; You *very seldom* have to loop over invocations of `awk`.

Note that `awk` is perfectly happy to read your string as a set of comma-delimited fields, and that it's able to loop over these:

```
printf '%s\n' "$var" |
awk -F ',' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i }'
```

With `var='data1,data2,data3'`, this would print

```
data1
data2
data3
```

---

Another shell solution that makes use of the `IFS` variable to split the `$var` value into bits while also using `set -f` to disable filename expansion:

```
set -f
oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=','

set -- $var

IFS=$oldIFS; unset oldIFS
set +f

for data do
    printf 'data = "%s"\n' "$data"
done
```